# Can we import Excel sheet from Powerpoint file to Power BI?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi, powerpoint, power-automate

I have excel sheets in powerpoint presentation. I want to import these sheets directly into Power BI  from Powerpoint. Can we do that? or is there any other to do that using Share Point or Flow.

Comment: You can extract all the excel sheets in a folder and then use "Folder" option in "Get Data" in Power BI to get all the data from all the sheets in Power BI at once.

Comment: http://www.excelandpowerbi.com/?p=326

May be this could add to your help